# File with random data but specific size

Tags: ruby, zip, filesize, rar

I am trying to generate a file in ruby that has a specific size. The content doesn't matter.

Here is what I got so far (and it works!):

```
File.open("done/#{NAME}.txt", 'w') do |f|
  contents = "x" * (1024*1024)
  SIZE.to_i.times { f.write(contents) }
end
```

The problem is: Once I zip or rar this file the created archive is only a few kb small. I guess thats because the random data in the file got compressed.

How do I create data that is more random as if it were just a normal file (for example a movie file)? To be specific: How to create a file with random data that keeps its size when archived?

Comment: Note, your `contents` is not random.  Arbitrary, maybe, but not random.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot guarantee an exact file size when compressing. However, as you suggest in the question, completely random data does not compress.

You can generate a random `String` using most random number generators. Even simple ones are capable of making hard-to-compress data, but you would have to write your own string-creation code. Luckily for you, Ruby comes with a built-in library that already has a convenient byte-generating method, and you can use it in a variation of your code:

```
require 'securerandom'
one_megabyte = 2 ** 20 # or 1024 * 1024, if you prefer

# Note use 'wb' mode to prevent problems with character encoding
File.open("done/#{NAME}.txt", 'wb') do |f|
  SIZE.to_i.times { f.write( SecureRandom.random_bytes( one_megabyte ) ) }
end
```

This file is not going to compress much, if at all. Many compressors will detect that and just store the file as-is (making a .zip or .rar file slightly larger than the original).

Comment: Works great! Thanks for taking your time to answer!

Comment: Perhaps "completely random data does not compress" is a bit strong. Part of a random string might be "abbbbbbbbbc". I expect any compression algorithm would be able to reduce the size of the entire string by at least six bytes.

Comment: Yes I qualified that in a previous version, but in the context of this question, I think that's an different subject. Once you get beyond a few bytes, and a *decent* RNG, then the probability of emitting a compressible string is so low that "does not compress" is essentially true.

Comment: @CarySwoveland: I just realised what you are trying to get at with *"Part of a random string might be "abbbbbbbbbc"...* and you are  wrong. You need to think about how a compression algorithm might identify this fortuitous sub-string in the compressed stream before you can see that this will not work (e.g. if it stored the byte offset, think of how many bytes you would need on average before a compressible segment turned up - the answer turns out to be for a random file *exactly* the same amount to offset the gain from compression)

Comment: Neil, if I do this: `str = ''`; `10_000_000.times { str << (65 + rand(58)).chr }; File.write('random',str) #=> 10000000` and then compress the file `random` using OS X's fairly basic *Archive Utility*, I get a file `random.zip` whose size is 7.4 MB. Am I missing your point?

Comment: @CarySwoveland: Yes you are missing the point. Your data is not completely random, you have selected only a subset of possible characters. The compressor is not finding patterns in the randomness, it is finding that you are only using 6 bits out of the 8 (and the ratio 0.75 is pretty close to the compression ratio you have got). In fact `Math.log(58)/Math.log(256) # => 0.7322` predicts your best possible compression ratio even better

Comment: On average, random data doesn't compress.  But any given output series of a true RNG might.  The tradeoff happens when you attach the header that says, "I am a ZIP file, and I found jack all to compress."  Most of the time you'll end up with a file slightly larger than when you started.

Answer (score 0):

For a given string size `N` and compression method `c` (e.g., from the [rubyzip](http://sourceforge.net/projects/rubyzip/), [libarchive](https://rubygems.org/gems/libarchive) or [seven_zip_ruby](https://rubygems.org/gems/seven_zip_ruby) gems), you want to find a string `str` such that:

```
str.size == c(str).size == N
```

I'm doubtful that you can be assured of finding such a string, but here's a way that should come close:

- Step 0: Select a number `m` such that `m > N`.
- Step 1: Generate a random string `s` with `m` characters.
- Step 2: Compute `str = c(str)`. If `str.size <= N`, increase `m` and repeat Step 1; else go to Step 3.
- Step 3: Return `str[0,N]`.

Comment: I think you have re-phrased the OPs question to the point it is no longer the same. I believe that OP just wants to generate "typical" non-compressible files, and does not want a precise match, nor a discussion on the compressibility or not of random strings.